# Simple regex question?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, parsing

In the streams I am parsing I need to parse something in this pattern:

```
<b>PaintTitle</b></td><td class=detail valign="top" align=left><div align=left><font size=small><b>The new great album by Pet Shop Boys</b>
```

How would I get the string `"The new great album by Pet Shop Boys"` where `<b>PaintTitle</b>` is guaranteed to be once per album?

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are due to the common response that RegEx should not be used for parsing HTML.  Something like the Html Agility Pack is almost always a better idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using regex, you can try this instead:

```
(?:<b>PaintTitle<\/b>).*?<b>(.*?)<\/b>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:<b>PaintTitle<\/b>).*<b>(.*)<\/b>
```

Match group 1 is "The new great album by Pet Shop Boys" with that expression.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I will give it a try now.

Comment: m.Groups [0].Value returns the whole string. Not just "The new great album by Pet Shop Boys", do you know why?

Comment: m.Groups[1] also returns the wrong result. It returns a sample way ahead of the stream. Can we make it so that it matches the first <b> after the album title?

Comment: @Joan Venge: I tested it in Perl against your string and it was okay for me. I'd need to see more of the stream to give you a better expression. I'll also echo what the comments to your question say: why do this with a regular expression? It's making things harder than they should be.

Comment: Thanks, the reason I use regex is, I just need a dumb string parser that gives me a list of values from a stream. Do you mean there are better ways for this? It's nothing like a compiler thing though.

Comment: Replace the .* with the non-greedy version: .*? and it might work better for you.